# Bloc doesn't provide the state flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am new to Flutter, and bloc too. I got the idea, how bloc works. But When I create a simple app as the first step of my note app. The bloc doesn't give the data. This simple app has two screens. list screen and Notedetailscreen. Button in NoteDetailScreen tapped, data does not print to the text widget.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/bloc/note_bloc.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/list_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<NoteBloc>(
      create: (context) => NoteBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: ListScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

note_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'note_event.dart';
part 'note_state.dart';

class NoteBloc extends Bloc<NoteblocEvent, NoteblocState> {
  NoteBloc() : super(NoteblocInitial());

  @override
  Stream<NoteblocState> mapEventToState(
    NoteblocEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event == NoteSaveEvent) {
      yield NoteSaveState(state);
    }
  }
}
```

```
part of 'note_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class NoteblocEvent {}

class NoteSaveEvent extends NoteblocEvent {
  NoteSaveEvent(this.text);

  final text;
}
```

note_state.dart

```
part of 'note_bloc.dart';

@immutable
abstract class NoteblocState {}

class NoteblocInitial extends NoteblocState {}

class NoteSaveState extends NoteblocState {
  NoteSaveState(this.text);

  final text;
}
```

list_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/note_detail_screen.dart';

class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListScreenState createState() => _ListScreenState();
}

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('hi'),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NoteDetailScreen(),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note_detailscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/bloc/note_bloc.dart';

class NoteDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteDetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NoteDetailScreenState createState() => _NoteDetailScreenState();
}

class _NoteDetailScreenState extends State<NoteDetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context).add(NoteSaveEvent('hi'));
            },
            child: Text('click'),
          ),
          BlocBuilder<NoteBloc, NoteblocState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Text(state.toString());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your bloc, state, and event looks fine. When you push screen you might need to use `BlocProvider` again. So try this:

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/bloc/note_bloc.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/list_screen.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  NoteBloc _noteBloc = NoteBloc();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<NoteBloc>(
      create: (context) => _noteBloc(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: ListScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

list_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/note_detail_screen.dart';

class ListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ListScreenState createState() => _ListScreenState();
}

class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Text('hi'),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(value: BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context), child: NoteDetailScreen()),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note_detailscreen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:note_demo_bloc/bloc/note_bloc.dart';

class NoteDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteDetailScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NoteDetailScreenState createState() => _NoteDetailScreenState();
}

class _NoteDetailScreenState extends State<NoteDetailScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context).add(NoteSaveEvent('hi'));
            },
            child: Text('click'),
          ),
          BlocBuilder<NoteBloc, NoteblocState>(
            bloc: BlocProvider.of<NoteBloc>(context),
            builder: (context, state) {
              return Text(state.toString());
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no bro. it doesn't work.  If I provide bloc above MaterialApp, it will be available on all screens. right?

Comment: No it won't be available if you push a screen.

Comment: You vote down only if the answer must improve, and not if it wasn't the solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

So, this is not an answer of your question but consider that as alternative (for future users of SO).
As state management is a free choice, and everyone could manage that as it’s “modus operandi“ this helper class “home made” could be a good choice.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:core';

class Method {
  Method(this.name, this.params);

  final String name;
  final Map<String, Object> params;
}

class _Controller {
  _Controller._();

  static final Map<String, _Controller> _this = new Map<String, _Controller>();
  final Map<String, Function(Method)> _funcs = new Map<String, Function(Method)>();

  factory _Controller(String identifier) => _this.putIfAbsent(identifier, () => _Controller._());

  Future<void> activateListener(String listenerId, Function(Method) function) async {
    if (function != null)
      _funcs.containsKey(listenerId) ? _funcs[listenerId] = function : _funcs.putIfAbsent(listenerId, () => function);
  }

  Future<void> deactivateListener(String listenerId) async =>
      _funcs.removeWhere((String key, Function(Method) func) => key == listenerId);

  Future<void> removeListener(String identifier) async =>
      _this.removeWhere((String key, _Controller mClass) => key == identifier);

  Future<void> callMethod(String methodName, {Map<String, Object> params}) async =>
      Future.forEach(_funcs.values.where((v) => v != null), (func) async => func.call(Method(methodName, params)));
}

mixin MethodListener on Object {
  _Controller _getController(String identifier) => _Controller(identifier ?? this.runtimeType.toString());

  Future<void> activateListener({String identifier, List<String> identifiers}) async {
    if (identifiers != null && identifiers.length > 0)
      identifiers.forEach(
          (String currentId) => _getController(currentId).activateListener(this.hashCode.toString(), onMethodListener));
    else
      _getController(identifier).activateListener(this.hashCode.toString(), onMethodListener);
  }

  Future<void> deactivateListener({String identifier, List<String> identifiers}) async {
    if (identifiers != null && identifiers.length > 0)
      identifiers.forEach((String currentId) => _getController(currentId).deactivateListener(this.hashCode.toString()));
    else
      _getController(identifier).deactivateListener(this.hashCode.toString());
  }

  Future<void> removeListener({String identifier}) async => _getController(identifier).removeListener(identifier);

  void onMethodListener(Method method) async => null;

  Future<void> callMethodOn(String identifier, String methodName, {Map<String, Object> params}) async =>
      _getController(identifier).callMethod(methodName, params: params);
}

class MethodManager with MethodListener {
  MethodManager._();

  static MethodManager _this;

  factory MethodManager() {
    if (_this == null) _this = MethodManager._();
    return _this;
  }

  Future<void> callMethodOnWidgets(List<String> identifiers, String methodName, {Map<String, Object> params}) async =>
      identifiers.forEach((String currentId) => callMethodOn(currentId, methodName, params: params));

  @override
  Future<void> callMethodOn(String identifier, String methodName, {Map<String, Object> params}) async =>
      super.callMethodOn(identifier, methodName, params: params);
}
```

then you can implements classes with “`with MethodListener`” as follows:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:yourpackagehere/utils/XMethods.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String NAME = "Test";

  @override
  createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> with MethodListener {
  String _ciao;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.activateListener(identifier: Test.NAME);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    this.deactivateListener(identifier: Test.NAME);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: Text(_ciao));
  }

  @override
  void onMethodListener(Method method) {
    switch (method.name) {
      case "say_hello":
        if (mounted) {
           setState(() {
        _ciao = method.params["my_string"];
                        });
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

From everywhere (from widgets or classes):

```
MethodManager().callMethodOn(Test.NAME, "say_hello", params: {"my_string": "SIAMO CAMPIONI DI EUROPA!!!"});
```

Comment: it may be helpful to others. what about my problem?